# I am unable to import apiai on pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried `import apiai` on pycharm, but it didn't work so I ran `pip install apiai` then freezed to the `requirements.txt` it still didn't work on pycharm.

I went and tested my code in the prompt after i ran it in the `env` environment and it worked just fine.
My question is how can i make it work on `pycharm` too ?

Comment: Check that you've configured the right interpreter for your project.

Comment: Hello, i'm still relatively new to pycharm, can you state the steps in more details, thanks.

Comment: Check this [Configuring Python virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) docs and be sure that you've installed `apiai` in configured interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On pycharm go to

File > Settings > project interpreter.. Under this add your env as an interpreter.